# What's Hans-Olaf Henkel's position on the EU?

Tags: european-union, brexit, germany, european-parliament

In a speech that was vociferously interrupted, MEP Hans-Olaf Henkel [accused](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GA_FBhRtep0) Juncker of being the "[Commission] president who lost Britain" and said that Junker's pinning of the blame on Cameron was "one of the biggest smoke screens in history".

I'm trying to understand what in Henkel's background could have motivated such 
an attack. Looking at his [biography on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans-Olaf_Henkel), I see he *was* an AfD member. Also, one of (few of) Henkel's positions mentioned there is not exactly unificatory: he called for the Euro to be split in two currencies (north and south).

Adding that to Henkel's accusation that Junker was power-grabbing and centralizing, I'm getting the impression Henkel is a sort of half-house Euroskeptik, i.e. he wants the EU, but with less integration. Is that a good summary, or is there more background that can be related to his animosity toward Junker and Henkel's position on the EU in general?

Comment: His position changed over time, notably in protest of the handling of the Eurozone crisis. So one would have to look for recent statements (which I haven't) and not the ancient history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Henkel has been mostly quiet since he left the European Parliament in 2019, so I'll give an answer that reflects his positions at that time. Unfortunately, my sources are in German, as I have not been able to find interviews in English. I've provided translations where necessary.

> **I'm getting the impression Henkel is a sort of half-house Euroskeptik, i.e. he wants the EU, but with less integration**

**This appears to be accurate. However, his opposition to EU centralisation seems to stem mostly<sup>1</sup> from his support for right-wing economic ideas of minimal state intervention in the free market.**

This can be seen in the way he frames his opposition to EU integration.

He has often expressed concern about the different economic cultures of the European North and South. According to him "Südländer", like Italy, Greece (and sometimes France), have an economic culture characterized by state intervention, government spending and a weak currency that can be devalued to pay for these expenditures. On the other hand, "Nordländer", like Germany, the UK or the Netherlands are committed to free markets, austerity and maintaining a strong currency.

Henkel, who I would describe as economically right-wing, prefers the "northern" economic culture. At the same time he worries about the influence of the "southern" culture on politics. He sees measures like the European Deposit Insurance Scheme or a European Unemployment Insurance as indications of increased "southern" (big government) influences on Europe and opposes them on these grounds.

His proposal to split the Euro was made along those lines, as indicated by [this interview with ntv from 2012](https://www.n-tv.de/politik/Schaeuble-hat-mich-sehr-enttaeuscht-article7164851.html):

> Ich bin für Europa und meine deshalb, wir sollten einen Schritt zurückgehen und den Euro passend zu den beiden vorherrschenden Finanz-, Budget- und Wirtschaftskulturen machen. Dann sollten die Nicht-Euro-Länder zum Beitritt in einen Nord-Euro eingeladen werden. Dies würden sie teilweise auch annehmen. Vielleicht kann man ja in 20 Jahren wieder zusammenkommen, dann, wenn sich die Verhältnisse angeglichen haben. Die Südländer einschließlich Frankreichs könnten mit einem abgewerteten Euro wieder wachsen. [...] Frankreich könnte mit dem verbleibenden Euro die Politik machen, die es immer machen wollte, mit einer von der Politik abhängigen Zentralbank und gelegentlichen Währungsabwertungen.

> I am pro-Europe and therefore think we should take a step back and make the euro fit the two prevailing financial, budgetary and economic cultures. Then the non-euro countries should be invited to join a northern euro. Some of them would accept this. Perhaps the two euros could come together again in 20 years' time, if the conditions have aligned. The southern countries, including France, could grow again with a devalued euro. [...] With the remaining euro, France could pursue the policy it always wanted to pursue, with a central bank dependent on politics and occasional currency devaluations.

This also informed his opposition to Brexit, as he saw the UK as an important counterweight to "southern" influence.

In [this interview with "The European" from July of 2018](https://www.theeuropean.de/hans-olaf-henkel/14423-interview-mit-hans-olaf-henkel-2) he states:

> Wir verlieren mit Großbritannien einen Nordstaat. Immer wenn es in der EU um sozialistische Themen, oder mehr Staat oder mehr Europa ging, dann war Großbritannien zusammen mit den Niederlanden, den nordischen aber auch baltischen Ländern und Deutschland immer in der Lage, sich einigermaßen an den Lissabon Vertrag zu halten und nicht weiter zu gehen.

> With Great Britain we are losing a northern state. Whenever the EU has been discussing socialist issues, or more government, or more Europe, Britain, together with the Netherlands, the Nordic but also Baltic countries and Germany, has always been able to somewhat stick to the Lisbon Treaty and not go further.

In [this guest article for Focus from October of 2017](https://www.focus.de/politik/experten/gastbeitrag-von-hans-olaf-henkel-faktenglaeubigkeit-wird-ausgenutzt-wie-politiker-die-buerger-ruhig-stellen_id_6503186.html), he even claims that proponents of a bigger European government support Brexit because it allows them to further their goals:

> Die britische Verfassung ist nicht kodifiziert und auf Kontinuität und Regeltreue angelegt. Beides hat in der EU keinen Platz mehr. Auch die marktwirtschaftliche Tradition steht mit dem Dogma der Vergemeinschaftung in Konflikt. Die zwei Präsidenten von Parlament und Kommission, Schulz und Juncker, wollen daher den Brexit sogar forcieren, um ihre vertiefte Union auszubauen.

> The British constitution is not codified and is designed for continuity and rule-following. Both no longer have a place in the EU. The free-market tradition also conflicts with the dogma of communitarisation. The two presidents of the Parliament and the Commission, Schulz and Juncker, therefore even want to push Brexit in order to expand their deepened union.

This would also explain his criticism of Juncker in particular. Although in the later interview with "The European", it seems he has stopped claiming that Juncker secretly supports Brexit and places that accusation on Guy Verhofstadt and other "dreamers of a United States of Europe" instead.

So he seems (and claims) to support the EU but opposes centralization on both economic grounds and the fact that it risks losing members (as indicated by Brexit) and strenghtens right-wing extremists. In the interview with "The European", he says of the "dreamers of a United Stated of Europe":

> Die ignorieren völlig, dass als Nebenprodukt dieser Politik die ganzen Rechtsradikalen überall auftauchen und ihnen einen Strich durch die Rechnung machen.

> They're completely ignoring the fact that as a by-product of this policy, all the right-wing radicals<sup>2</sup> are popping up all over the place and giving them a run for their money.

---

<sup>1</sup> In the ntv interview, he also expressed support for DeGaulle's idea of a "Europa der Vaterländer", a Europe of nation states, so his opposition to European integration is at least somewhat based around ideas of national sovereignty as well.

<sup>2</sup> A quick note on his AfD membership: Henkel was a founding member of the AfD in 2013 and left in 2015 after the party's right wing took over control. Since then he has publicly critizised the AfD on many occasions, [going so far as to calling it a monster that he helped create](https://presse.wdr.de/plounge/tv/wdr_fernsehen/2015/11/20151108_westpol.html). The AfD has undergone various processes of radicalization to become the party it is today (in fact, the right wing of 2015 has since been pushed out by the even further right). Henkel left early on in that process.